# Why does Spring data's query builder not work for limiting query results?

Tags: java, spring-data

#### Context

I have defined a repository interface (JpaRepository) and i want to limit the query results [(documentation)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).
I need the first result(s) and i prefer not to use pagination for limiting query size. I would rather use the query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository infrastructure for constraining queries over the repository entity.

#### Specifics

I am building queries with property traversals and static ordering along with limiting the result. It all works except limiting the result.

At first i thought the reason for the limit query failure is they might not play well together. Then i stripped it down to just limiting the result and it is not working as expected.

After stripping it to just limiting query results i have tried :

- EntityName findTop , queryFirst  - however the query result returns more than one element. It needs to be declared as a List instead of EntityName findTopBy... as exemplified in the documentation
- queryFirst1ByOrderBySomePropertyDesc , findTopByOrderBySomePropertyDesc , findFirstByProperty(property) etc.

It always works with property expressions or static ordering but litimg the results is ignored.

Could it be that this does not work on all database systems ? (I use Oracle Database 11G Release 2).

Or could it be the data jpa version? I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa which has the spring-data-jpa 1.5.2.RELEASE and spring-data-oracle with the spring-data-jdbc-core 1.0.0

I have yet to find any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It was the version.

It turns out i had an older Spring Data JPA version (1.5.2) and the Top and First keywords where only introduced after Spring Data JPA 1.7.0 .

I ended up applying pagination to my queries (usingthe the Pageable method argument).